# RxJS distinct operator is not taking distinct values from an array of objects

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using an image API to pull some image information and I want to create an array with unique author names for each image returned. I'm using the `distinct` RxJS to try to do this, but right now the entire objects are being returned.

Here's what the API data comes back looking like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "117",
    "author": "Daniel Ebersole",
    "width": 1544,
    "height": 1024,
    "url": "https://unsplash.com/photos/Q14J2k8VE3U",
    "download_url": "https://picsum.photos/id/117/1544/1024"
  },
  {
    "id": "118",
    "author": "Rick Waalders",
    "width": 1500,
    "height": 1000,
    "url": "https://unsplash.com/photos/d-Cr8MEW5Uc",
    "download_url": "https://picsum.photos/id/118/1500/1000"
  }
]
```

Here's a portion of code that I've simplified for easier reading:

```
export class AppComponent {

  authors; // using an array of strings for this doesn't work when I try to set it from the subscribe()

  ngOnInit() {
    const apiURI = 'https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=2&limit=100';

    const authors$ = this.http.get(apiURI).pipe(
      distinct((item: Image) => item.author),
      tap(author => console.log(author))
    );

    authors$.subscribe(authors => this.authors = authors);
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}

export interface Image {
    id: number;
    author: string;
    width: number;
    height: number;
    url: string;
    download_url: string;
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6cwp5)

This is weird to me, as there's another [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-distinct) I've found with examples that does essentially the same thing with an array of objects.

It's the first time I'm working with the `distinct` operator so I'm sure I'm missing something, but I haven't been able to figure out what it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.http.get will emit array of values - not each value separately.
That's why distinct is not valid here.
But you can convert array of values to emit each value separately with mergeAll operator

const authors$ = this.http.get(apiURI).pipe(
      mergeAll(),
      distinct((item: Image) => item.author)
    );

Answer (score 0):

`Flatten` the array first, then apply `distinct` and collect.

```
export class AppComponent {
  authors: string[];

  ngOnInit() {
    const apiURI = 'https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=2&limit=100';
    const authors$ = this.http.get(apiURI).pipe(
      flatMap(x => x),
      distinct((item: Image) => item.author),
      toArray()  
    );

    authors$.subscribe(authors => console.log(JSON.stringify(authors)));
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

// Here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6cwp5

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct` will let you specify the field to check by, on itself it will not map the object to return just the author's name (or the selected field).

you can use a `switchMap` to achieve that:

```js
const authors$ = this.http.get(apiURI).pipe(
      mergeAll(),
      distinct((item: Image) => item.author),
      switchMap((author: any) => of(author.author))
    );
```

I updated your stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6cwp5

Comment: This is awesome, I didn't know much about `switchMap` before this. If I hadn't already marked an answer as correct (I took part of their solution and yours), I'd mark this one. I wish I had enough rep to upvote. But I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, guys :)
`distinct()` is supposed to work with a stream emitting mutiple values. But we deal with a single value coming from api call! We don't need rxjs to perform a synchronous array transformation - it's just not the right tool for that.

The task is: take a list of items as input, return a list of unique authors. It's trivially done with plain JS code or with lodash/underscore.

```
function getUniqueAuthors(items Item[]): string[] {
  const authors = items.map(item => item.author);
  return [...(new Set(authors).values()];
  // or can do this with lodash: return _.unique(authors);
}

// transform results inside subscribe()
this.http.get(apiURI).subscribe(items => {
  this.authors = getUniqueAuthors(items)
})

// or can get fancy and perform mapping inside the pipe:
this.http.get(apiURI)
  .pipe(map(getUniqueAuthors))
  .subscribe(authors => {
    this.authors = authors
  })
```

I humbly believe it's a more straightforward approach than transforming an array into a stream emitting individual items and then collecting them back into an array.